# Cross-compiling for linux arm/7: clang error: argument unused during compilation '-marm'

Tags: go, cgo

**What is the reason and how to solve it? Please..**

cmd : `CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7  go build`

output:

```
# runtime/cgo
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-marm' [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

- OS: macOS Big Sur
- Golang verson: go1.17 darwin/amd64

Comment: See: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [fine manual](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo):

> When cross-compiling, you must specify a C cross-compiler for cgo to use. You can do this by setting the generic CC_FOR_TARGET or the more specific CC_FOR_${GOOS}_${GOARCH} (for example, CC_FOR_linux_arm) environment variable when building the toolchain using make.bash, or you can set the `CC` environment variable any time you run the `go` tool.

So you need to specify the cross-compiler for CGo, e.g. like so:

`CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7  go build`

For C++ code also add `CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`.

You'll need to have `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `libc6-dev-armhf-cross` packages installed for the above to work (on Linux, don't know about Mac).

Comment: Does not work on MacOS Ventora apple silicon: 

`cgo: C compiler "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" not found: exec: "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc": executable file not found in $PATH`